# Disable scrolling and remove scrollbar in Windows 8 webview

Tags: javascript, windows-8, webview, scroll

Hello as part of a Windows 8 metro app I use a webview and I want to disable horizontal scrolling so the user don't navigate away from the info by mistake.

I have tried putting it inside a scrollviewer and then disabling the horizontal scrolling there but the scrollbar and scrolling in the webviewer is active.

The user still has to be able to use the webviewer so disabling all input for it wont work.. :-)

Hope someone has an easy solution..

EDIT:

As written in comments I have been trying to do it using JavaScript to no success.

using

```
.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { "document.body.scroll = 'no';" });
```

and

```
.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { "document.body.style.overflow ='hidden';" });
```

Comment: been trying to see if it can be done useing javascript and the invoke script function of the webview useing `webview.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { "document.body.style.overflow = hidden;" });` but that throws an exception..

Comment: needed to use 'hidden' and then it will run, only problem is that is still dont work.

Comment: also tried `document.body.scroll = 'no';` because I read that might work in IE but still no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is not possible..

In the end I ended up using

`string html = webBrowser1.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { "document.documentElement.outerHTML;" });`

to get the source of the page and then using regex.replace to change the html to not allow scrolling,, not a very elegant solution and not very universal but worked for me.

```
   string resultString = null;
        try
        {
            resultString = Regex.Replace(html, "<YOUR REGEX HERE, RegexOptions.Singleline);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            string errorMessage1 = ex.ToString();
            var messageDialog = new MessageDialog(errorMessage1);
            await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 XAML

<Grid>

<WebView
Height="400"
NavigationCompleted="theWebView_NavigationCompleted"
x:Name="theWebView" Source="http://blogs.msdn.com/ashish"
></WebView>

 </Grid>

Code

private
async void theWebView_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs
args)

        {

            string returnStr = await
theWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] {
SetBodyOverFlowHiddenString });

        }

        string SetBodyOverFlowHiddenString =
@"function SetBodyOverFlowHidden()

        {

            document.body.style.overflow =
'hidden';

            return 'Set Style to hidden';

        }

        // now call the function!enter code here

        SetBodyOverFlowHidden();";
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works?  Good answers need more than just a block of code.